# How to extract JSON data from an API python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to extract data from a JSON API but I get an error **string indices must be integers** i couldn't find anything about this here is my code:

```py
import requests
import json
name = input('input a name: ')
server = input('input a server: ')
response = requests.get('https://api.battlemetrics.com/players?fields[server]=name&filter[search]=' + name + '&filter[servers]=' + server + '&page[size]=10&include=server')
def jprint(obj):
    #create a formatted string of the Python JSON onject
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print (text)
pass_times = response.json()
jprint(pass_times)

status = []
for d in pass_times:
    time = d["online"]
    status.append(time)
print (status)
```

Comment: could you give me any name and server to get valid json?

Comment: Use another list for appending. That shouldn't come in the way of iterating.

Comment: @JasarOrion use 6354292 as server-id and "master oogway" as name.

Comment: @Ashok What do you mean by that?

Comment: Please show the complete trace of the error

Comment: Do you mean this ```Exception has occurred: TypeError
string indices must be integers
  line 15, in <module> time = d["online"]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
name = "master oogway"
server = "6354292"
response = requests.get('https://api.battlemetrics.com/players?fields[server]=name&filter[search]=' + name + '&filter[servers]=' + server + '&page[size]=10&include=server')
def jprint(obj):
    #create a formatted string of the Python JSON onject
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print (text)
pass_times = response.json()
#jprint(pass_times)

status = []
for data in pass_times["data"]:
  status.append(data["relationships"]["servers"]["data"][0]["meta"]["online"])

print(status)
```